# Covariance of Dirac Equation

Tags: lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation, spinors

In Bjorken and Drell "Relativistic Quantum Mechanics", problem 3 ch.2:

Given a free-particle spinor $u(p)$, construct $u(p+q)$ for $q \rightarrow 0$, with $p\cdot q \rightarrow 0$, in terms of $u(p)$ by making a Lorentz Transformation.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Start by figuring out an infinitesimal Lorentz boost that changes $p$ to $p+q$.

Comment: Can I treat p like it’s a spatial coordinate and q as dq and then try to find the Transformation Matrix (a) ?

Comment: Boosts don’t just change $(t,\mathbf x)$. They also change $(E,\mathbf p)$, and in a similar way.